# window.scroll not working on mobile (chrome) when element is wider than viewport

Tags: javascript, scroll

I use a script where i need window.scroll to detect element position and based on it change element classes. Now i have a problem with android phones and google chrom. On such devices when i have an element that is wider than 100vw it just counts wrong or to late. For me this is kind of important cause i have elements that are wider than 100vw and i create horizontal scrolling effects. Does everyone know how to get rid of that problem?

https://codepen.io/yabaikumo/pen/WNWrZMp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Test - 001</title>   
        
        <style>
            #top {
                background-color: red;
                height: 100vh; width: 100vw;
            }
    
            #middle {
                background-color: yellow;
                height: 59vh; width: 150vw;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
    
            #bottom {
                background-color: blue;
                height: 100vh; width: 100vw;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="top"></div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <div id="bottom"></div>
    </body>

    <script> 
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
            const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
            console.log(scrollPosition);
        });
    </script>

</html>
```